# SVG icon not showing when there is no internet in NextJS app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

[image]

[image]

As you see, at the attached images that `src` has an url, that is located inside the **nextjs public** folder. The issue is when there is no internet, as per logic the modal pops-up and i can see the expected file (svg icon) in my localhost but not in live dev environment. I've used `next/image` component for serving the file.

Why this is happening? Is there anything i did wrong? How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Are you lazy loading the modal ?

Comment: No. I'm not lazy loading the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is NextJs Image component only loads an Image Src when the Image is On the viewPort or some height away from the viewPort.

Now your modals logic works fine but by the time the Modal Pops up and next Js tries to Load the Image src, there isn't an internet connect to load it from where its hosted. It works fine the dev environment because NextJs only need to load it from the public folder but by the time you host the project live, all your static files are hosted in your "https://your-domain/icons/quiz/stages/nextwork.svg".

**Possible solution**

Now instead of loading the svg as a file you can load it internally in the modal as a element

1. First go to where you store the file, right click on it and open the file with vscode. That should display the file svg element properties. its should display something like this

```
<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M7.57617 16.25L13.8262 10L7.57617 3.75" stroke="#002854" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

2. Change all the svg property to pascal nameing convention e.g stroke-linecap --> strokeLinecap. or else react will throw an error

Now copy it and use it directly in your Modal component

```
<div className="svgWrapper">
<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M7.57617 16.25L13.8262 10L7.57617 3.75" stroke="#002854" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Now when you open the modal with no internet connection, you will not need to fetch any files on the client as the svg would have be among the compiled build code.

I hope this helps